# Permission issue using compass on Mac

Tags: macos, sass, file-permissions, compass-sass

I don't consider myself a Mac power user but permission in particular are confusing to me.

I am just trying to start a `compass watch` on a particular folder. I've done this a thousand times but for this new project it is giving me a permission error that I cannot seem to figure out:

```
compass watch
```

> > > Change detected at 08:43:26 to: partials/bootstrap.scss
> > >          create stylesheets/partials/bootstrap.css 
> > >       Errno::EACCES on line ["56"] of /Users/mikefielden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/compass-0.12.0/lib/compass/actions.rb: Permission denied - /Users/mikefielden/Dropbox/Projects/_Default Project/stylesheets/partials/bootstrap.css
> > >       Run with --trace to see the full backtrace

That is the only file it complains about...

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I just deleted that folder and started again and it worked, however I still don't understand why...

Comment: which folder did you delete? and i suggest that this should be added to the question instead of being an answer :)

Comment: I deleted the folder i was trying to watch and re-added it and boom it worked

Answer (score 3):

This is a common problem with SASS/Compass and the reason is that the cache is gets messed up.

The proper solution is to run `compass clean` and recompile.

Answer (score 0):

The user that is trying to write the bootstrap.css file does not have the permission to do so. Take a look at the directory holding the file or the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old and already answered, but I have run into the same issue and none of these answers helped me. Running

`sudo compass watch`

cures the issue for me. I'm guessing because I install using

`sudo compass install`.